# Regenerating Querying Database

Tags: architecture, cqrs, maintainability, event-sourcing

The site that I own has a simple CQRS architecture that is working well. An event is published and picked up by various subscribers, one of which keeps the reporting database in sync [in RavenDb].

Say, for example, my reporting database is corrupt/lost. With Event Sourcing I can replay the events and rebuild the reporting database, however I am [currently] not using event sourcing; I have a simple nHibernate persister to a relational store. Would the solution be to create a "regeneration" type of script which essentially would send all of the events based on the relational store (e.g. PersonCreatedEvent followed by 30xPersonLikedBlogPostEvent etc)? It's essentially doing the same thing as an Event Source would do, but the events are inferred from the relational model.

Kind of stumped here as maintainability and DR is obviously important.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't store events, you can't do regeneration. If you generate just "Created" events using your relational store, you wont be able to get any benefits from this "regeneration".

Comment: Thanks, I'm not too fussed about the benefits of regeneration from / true representation of the object history etc, but having a RavenDb reporting database is important for the performance SLA's of the site.  I'm moving to event sourcing, however. Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you stored all the commands sent to the server (in a log, for instance) you may send all the commands to the bus starting from the very first command till the last one, and you can reproduce all the query side. That is Command Sourcing. 
With a Command Sourcing you could easily go Event Sourcing whenever you feel ready.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement a full-blown event sourcing solution to achieve this. If you just store all your events in an event log, you can retrieve and replay them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a easy/quick solution for this. This is actually what you would need to do  if you were migrating data from relational to event sourced. As you have said, the only thing you can do is for each entity script the events in a plausible sequence (i.e. CreatedEvent then your other state changing events).  But when you capture these events, I'd store them so you can then just re-run them in the future.